# How to get modulus from a line for particular values in python

Tags: python

```
[('"SELLER_ID": "['5187296']"', '"GT_SELLER_ID":"['18149']"', '"TOTAL_TAG_COUNT": "['476']"', '"total_product_count":"['486']"', '"tag_count_diff": "['-10']"')]
```

I want to get modulus for `tag_count_diff/total_tag_count*100`.

Comment: The data you present doesn't seem to be a valid Python expression. The quotes around the numbers need to be escaped.

Comment: More Information please, how are those values stored? Is that line a string?

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator id's "%"

```
tag_count_diff % (total_tag_count*100)
```